# Adding a non-unique foreign key constraint in DB2

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, db2, constraints

I have these two (simplified to illustrate the question) tables:

```
create table CASE_INSTANCE (id int not null, stage_id int not null,
     primary key (id, stage_id));    
create table SAMPLE (id int not null, case_id int not null);
```

I want to add a constraint on SAMPLE so that CASE_ID must be a valid value of CASE_INSTANCE.ID .  However, I can't do this with a foreign key, because CASE_INSTANCE.ID is not unique.  How can I add a constraint to SAMPLE that will enforce this relationship?

This is for DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another table where `case_id` is unique, then reference it both from `CASE_INSTANCE` and `SAMPLE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to change the model, I'm afraid you'll have to enforce this with a trigger or in the application. However, if something depends on a case as opposed to case instance, it should be a child of that case, not the case instance. If you don't have a table where the case ID is unique, I'd say there's something wrong with your model.